# Problem Connecting Digital Ocean RPC Node to Polkadot-JS (NGINX Configuration Problem?)

Tags: polkadot-js, nodes, nginx

I have established an RPC node on a Digital Ocean droplet and configured NGINX and SSL according to the instructions at the polkadot wiki. Configurations below. Connecting on wss://koabd.rocks or wss://koabd.rocks:443 both produce the following ...  **The node accepts the incoming connection** (node output:  "accepting new connection 1/100") **but the polkadot-JS screen is stuck in "Waiting to establish a connection with the remote endpoint."**

What am I missing? Do I need to:

- set up a firewall and allow specific ports? (there are currently no firewalls in place)
- remove the IPv6only tag from the NGINX config?
- some other trick?

**My Node Configuration:**

```
./target/release/substrate \
--base-path ./gropocloudmoose \
--chain ./GropoSpec20230115Raw.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9955 \
--rpc-port 9944 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--enable-offchain-indexing=true \
--ws-external \
--state-pruning archive \
--blocks-pruning archive \
--ws-max-connections 100 \
--rpc-cors all \
--rpc-methods Safe \
--name gropocloudmoose \
--bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30344/p2p/12D3KooWMaj8rma6fWK71hHEgXzGre2FcfCPMD39LhPBTvQyMzk6 \
--password-interactive
```

**My NGINX Configuration:**

```
server {

    server_name koabd.rocks www.koabd.rocks;

    location / {
        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9955;
        include proxy_params;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/koabd.rocks/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/koabd.rocks/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.koabd.rocks) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = koabd.rocks) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name koabd.rocks www.koabd.rocks;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! Open the Nginx config for the site…
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/MYSITE

Erase EVERYTHING in the file (yes, everything) and set it back to just:

server {
server_name MYSITE;

location / {
proxy_buffers 16 4k;
proxy_buffer_size 2k;
proxy_pass http://localhost:MY-WS-PORT;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
}

THEN…. Re-engage certbot…

certbot --nginx

Finish your certbot prompts and you are good to go!

Nginx Config FIRST, Certbot SECOND.

Answer (score 1):

Connection to https://koabd.rocks does seem to work, so the nginx on https looks like its working and there is no issue with a firewall from the internet.

While accessing wss://koabd.rocks I did get an error aswell.

Do you see something in the access or error log for nginx?

And can you try adding

> ssl on;

on the server block?

Comment: I see a 502 Bad Gateway error when I try to access the url https://koabd.rocks directly. I cannot see any log or error files for my nginx (probably just don't know where to look). I tried adding "ssl on;" to my server block and got an error saying that "server on;" was deprecated and it could not run the nginx that way. I also tried setting ipv6only=off but the nginx server would not run with that either.

Comment: normally you can find the logs under /var/log/nginx/* . Check if you can find some info there.

Comment: Thanks! I found the logs and took a look at them. There is nothing obvious. In the access logs I see lots of GET and POST. In the error logs there are only a few lines: 2023/01/22 23:20:01 [notice] 103646#103646: using inherited sockets from "6;7;"
2023/01/23 00:22:12 [notice] 104666#104666: signal process started
2023/01/23 00:22:18 [notice] 104669#104669: signal process started

Comment: I find it strange that there are no entries from today in either file.

Comment: Yeah, thats strange. You should see something because https://koabd.rocks is accessible over the internet..

Comment: I think I see the error you are talking about... if I type koabd.rocks into the browser directly I get "{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}" could that have anything to do with it?