# NGINX Reverse Proxy JSON Parse Error

Tags: polkadot-js, proxy, wss, nginx

I have **NGINX and SSL set up on Digital Ocean Linux Ubuntu, running an RPC node**. The RPC node sees the Polkadot-JS/apps and accepts the connection but the Polkadot-JS/apps never sees anything in return and keeps waiting for a connection.

Going straight to the URL https://koabs.rocks, I get an **error:
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"},"id":null}**

How can I fix this?

My node configuration is:

```
./target/release/substrate \
--base-path ./gropocloudmoose \
--chain ./GropoSpec20230115Raw.json \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9955 \
--rpc-port 9944 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--enable-offchain-indexing=true \
--ws-external \
--state-pruning archive \
--blocks-pruning archive \
--ws-max-connections 100 \
--rpc-cors all \
--rpc-methods Safe \
--name gropocloudmoose \
--bootnodes /ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/30344/p2p/12D3KooWMaj8rma6fWK71hHEgXzGre2FcfCPMD39LhPBTvQyMzk6 \
--password-interactive
```

And my NGINX configuration for this site is:

```
server {

    server_name koabd.rocks www.koabd.rocks;

    location / {
        proxy_buffers 16 4k;
        proxy_buffer_size 2k;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9955;
        include proxy_params;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/koabd.rocks/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/koabd.rocks/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.koabd.rocks) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = koabd.rocks) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name koabd.rocks www.koabd.rocks;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solutions is the same as for this question: [Problem Connecting Digital Ocean RPC Node to Polkadot-JS (NGINX Configuration Problem?)](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6895/problem-connecting-digital-ocean-rpc-node-to-polkadot-js-nginx-configuration-pr/7092#7092)

**SOLVED!** Open the Nginx config for the site… sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/MYSITE

Erase EVERYTHING in the file (yes, everything) and set it back to just:

server { server_name MYSITE;

location / { proxy_buffers 16 4k; proxy_buffer_size 2k; proxy_pass http://localhost:MY-WS-PORT; proxy_http_version 1.1; proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade"; proxy_set_header Host $host; } }

THEN…. Re-engage certbot…

certbot --nginx

Finish your certbot prompts and you are good to go!

Nginx Config FIRST, Certbot SECOND.